# AngularJS parse string to html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to parse string to html using `$sce`, but it doesn't work.
My function on `angular controller`:

```
function renderHtml(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
}
```

html:

```
<div style="width:100px; word-wrap: break-word" ng-bind-html="ctrl.renderHtml(ctrl.newfield.showConditions)"></div>
```

value of variable `newfield.showConditions` = `gender <br /> vk`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you only need line breaks you should be able to enter `\r\n` instead of `<br>` by the way

Comment: what is an error??

Comment: do u inject dependency???

Comment: @Aides it doesn't help

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad no errors

Comment: did you include ng-sanitize??

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad no, I didn't. Is it necessary?

Comment: but u tell me injected it???!!!!

Comment: @SSH, i am injected `$sce`, I thought that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yuhayu/edit?html,js,console,output) for your scenario and it works fine. The changes I have done are exposing the controller method, changing use of reserved word `string` to `str` and adding `$sce` as dependency:

```
$scope.renderHtml = renderHtml;

function renderHtml(str) {
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
}
```

Comment: Did you see the link to JSBin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and include `ng-sanitize`

```
function renderHtml($sce,string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. add ngSanitize depenednecy to app.

```
 angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

and also add ngSanitize js file.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])

.controller('ctrl',function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.html =$sce.trustAsHtml(
     ' this is <br> a <em>test</em>');
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <p ng-bind-html="html" ></p>
  </div>
</div>
```