# Angular 1.5 display html into templates with filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have html display as escaped safe html, but i want real html.

```
angular.module('wp.controllers').filter('unsafe', unsafe);
unsafe.$inject = ['$sce'];
function unsafe($sce) { return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
}; }
```

i want to make this in templates:

```
{{post.content | unsafe }}
```

but it not works, but this is works:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content | unsafe"></div>
```

but it is ugly, i want beautiful

Comment: do u inject ngSanitize depenedency??

Comment: is it part of ngSanitize? i have not included ngSanitize

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907480/angularjs-parse-string-to-html/36908150#36908150